# Finding Speech (voice command) Language+Region/Culture setting?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, culture, region

**Question**:

I need to retrieve the language+region code for the default WP8 speech recognition service.  In the phone GUI this is under 'Speech'->'Speech language'.  How do I get to this attribute programmatically?

NOTE: AppResources.ResourceLanguage or AppResources.Culture does not provide the attribute I need as they are the value behind 'Language+Region'->'Phone language' only.

**Background**:

I have successfully used an English (en-US) VoiceCommandDefinition.xml (VCD.xml) file with my WP8 app.  There are problems when using speech recognition with a language-specific VCD.xml for languages other than English.  If the 'Speech'->'Speech language' attribute on the phone does not exactly match the 'lang' value on the VCD.xml none of the application's voice commands will be available.

To get speech recognition to work therefore I really need to dynamically change the 'lang' attribute in my VCD.xml when loaded so that I can make es-US look like es-MX as a best-effort alternate-language command-set.  Only when this value on the VCD.xml matches the value in 'Speech'->'Speech language' will the application's voice commands to the application load and be usable.

NOTE: the 'Language+Region'->'Phone language' setting on the phone only determines which pronunciation of the application name is used and not the actual commands.  Example, 'Language+Region'->'Phone language' and VCD.xml 'lang' attribute = 'es-US' while 'Speech'->'Speech language' = 'es-MX' causes no application voice commands to appear because the regions do not match.  What matters is the 'Speech'->'Speech language' attribute which I need to programmatically access during runtime.

**Researched Sources**:

I read the pages associated with  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207021%28v=vs.105%29.aspx (among others) before submitting this question as well as any Stackoverflow or MSDN forum pages that seemed relevant.

Thanks for your help if you can provide it.

P.S. I have also posted this question to the [Microsoft Windows Phone 8 Develpoment Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3730f90c-d99c-4a90-b17a-9ac9dd7ff537/finding-speech-voice-command-languageregion-setting?forum=wpdevelop#3730f90c-d99c-4a90-b17a-9ac9dd7ff537) with no relevant answers yet so if you answer here and there I'll vote you up in both places!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string langSetOnPhone = new Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer().GetVoice().Language;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(langSetOnPhone) && langSetOnPhone == "en-US")
{
   //Do your work here
}
else
{
   //Show relavant message
}
```

Hope this helps.